# Can I increase the power of my Garland of Greatness after the G-Lover seasion has ended?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I managed to finish one G-Lover run in-season, and received the Garland.

Can I still do G-Lover run to increase the power of the Garland, or is it forever stuck at the current power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ascended in G-Lover out of season, and the Garland that I already had has now indeed increased in power.